# Execution of ant file within exec task

Tags: java, ant

I want to run my ant i.e. build.xml file in parallel execution along with the ongoing execution of a task.
I am using Exec task to achieve this. i.e. I am using ant to run the build.xml file within Exec task but facing the following error:
ERROR: exec doesn't support the nested "ant" element.

My excerpt of the code is:

```
<if>
    <istrue value="${parallel.exec}" />
    <then>

        <!-- Parallel execution of task -->
        <mkdir dir="${buildroot.dir}/product/${build-log.dir}" />
        <exec dir="../../apollo" executable="/bin/sh" spawn="true">
            <ant antfile="${buildroot.dir}/product/abs-build.xml" />
        </exec>
    </then>
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll, `<exec>` simply doesn't support arbitrary tasks as nested elements, just what the manual page lists.

In  order to run Ant you'd use something like

```
<exec dir="../../apollo" executable="/bin/sh" spawn="true">
    <arg value="${ant.home}/bin/ant"/>
    <arg value="-f"/>
    <arg file="${buildroot.dir}/product/abs-build.xml" />
</exec>
```

Comment: I get the error as  arg doesn't support the "location" attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a target like this

```
<target name="antcaller">
 <ant antfile="yourantfile" target="do something" />
 ...
```

and then can call it

Comment: how ill execute this ant file within exec? This part of my code is already in a target